# Server procces the commands

Tags: java, if-statement

I currently have a server that receives information from the client.
However in my code I have a if statement for every command I receive. Can this be done better?

```
    Public class receiveRepository implements Runnable {


    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (connected) {
           // receive stuff
           if(receive.equals("something"){
               //do something
          }
           else if(receive.equals("something else")){
                //do something else
             }
         //ect
        }
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At initialization time (i.e., once only), build a `Map<String, Consumer<X>>`, look up the command in the map to get a Consumer, and then call consumer.accept().

The type 'X' may be Void, if your consumer functions are effectively static, or perhaps receiveRepository so you can pass 'this'.

Answer (score 0):

Or maybe just:

```
switch(receive){
    case "something":
        //do something
        break;
    case "something else":
        //do something else
        break;
    default:
        //nothing from above
        break;
}
```